# How to get the time value alone when using input type=time, angular scope gets updated with date,time & timezone?

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using below input tag and trying to get the time angular js controller,

```
 <input type="time" ng-model="fnBeg">
```

but I'm getting like "Thu Jan 01 1970 14:59:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" in scope variable ($scope.fnBeg).

Why is that happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input `type="time"` takes input as date object (in browsers where it's supported). So in angularjs model value it'll give as stringified date object. If you want only time string inside its scope var model then you can just get time from the date object & assign back to that model on change of that input.

```
<input type="time" ng-model="fnBeg" ng-change="onFnBegChange(fnBeg)">
```

In controller you can write that function as:

```
$scope.onFnBegChange = function(fnBeg) {
  $scope.fnBeg = fnBeg.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

[**Demo Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EzWI0uhSyUG2tGcbzZjv?p=preview)